# how to add data from one data frame to another

Tags: r

I have two data sets

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:12, .Label = c("A0A0A6YXQ7", 
"A0A0A6YXS5", "A0A0A6YXW8", "A0A0A6YXX6", "A0A0A6YXZ1", "A0A0A6YY28", 
"A0A0A6YY43", "A0A0A6YY47", "A0A0A6YY78", "A0A0A6YY89", "A0A0A6YY91", 
"A0A0A7NQN9"), class = "factor")), .Names = "from", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

and

```
df2 <- structure(list(from = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A0A0A6YXQ7", 
"A0A0A6YXW8", "A0A0A6YXX6", "A0A0A6YXZ1", "A0A0A6YY28", "A0A0A6YY47", 
"A0A0A6YY78", "A0A0A6YY91"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Arhgap15", "Igtp", "MumuTL", 
"Myo1f", "Pak2", "pol"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("from", 
"to"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

df1 and df2 have a column named `from` 
all strings in df1 should be in df2. if they are not , I want to place them the exact order they appear in the df1 and for column `to`they get NA

for example, in df2 the following strings are missing

A0A0A6YXS5 and A0A0A6YY43 and A0A0A6YY89 and A0A0A7NQN9

so the output will look like this

```
From       To
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXS5  NA
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY43  NA
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY89  NA
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A7NQN9  NA
```

One solution which is not a good one is to merge these two data frames

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "from", all.x = TRUE)
```

which will work for some data but not others

So lets look at a bigger data

```
df1<- structure(list(from = structure(c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L), .Label = c("A0A023J6K5", "A0A023J6L7", "A0A023J6M1", "A0A067XG53", 
"A0A067XKM5", "A0A067XKP8", "A0A067XKR4", "A0A067XKW4", "A0A067XKW7", 
"A0A0A6YXQ7", "A0A0A6YXS5", "A0A0A6YXW8", "A0A0A6YXX6", "A0A0A6YXZ1", 
"A0A0A6YY28", "A0A0A6YY43", "A0A0A6YY47", "A0A0A6YY78", "A0A0A6YY89", 
"A0A0A6YY91", "A0A0A7NQN9"), class = "factor")), .Names = "from", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

and

```
df2 <- structure(list(from = structure(c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("A0A023J6K5", 
"A0A023J6L7", "A0A023J6M1", "A0A023T778", "A0A067XG53", "A0A067XKM5", 
"A0A067XKP8", "A0A067XKR4", "A0A067XKW4", "A0A0A6YXQ7", "A0A0A6YXW8", 
"A0A0A6YXX6", "A0A0A6YXZ1", "A0A0A6YY28", "A0A0A6YY47", "A0A0A6YY78", 
"A0A0A6YY91"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(7L, 10L, 1L, 
4L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 8L), .Label = c("Arhgap15", 
"Cask", "COXI", "Igtp", "Magohb", "MumuTL", "Myo1f", "ND1", "ND4", 
"Pak2", "pol"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("from", "to"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I need then to get the following output

```
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXS5  
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY43  
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY89  
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A7NQN9  
A0A023J6K5  ND4
A0A023J6L7  ND1
A0A023J6M1  ND4
A0A067XG53  Cask
A0A067XKM5  ND1
A0A067XKP8  COXI
A0A067XKR4  ND4
A0A067XKW4  ND1
A0A067XKW7
```

but if I do this

```
#> merge(df1, df2, by = "from", all.x = TRUE)
#         from       to
#1  A0A023J6K5      ND4
#2  A0A023J6L7      ND1
#3  A0A023J6M1      ND4
#4  A0A067XG53     Cask
#5  A0A067XKM5      ND1
#6  A0A067XKP8     COXI
#7  A0A067XKR4      ND4
#8  A0A067XKW4      ND1
#9  A0A067XKW7     <NA>
#10 A0A0A6YXQ7    Myo1f
#11 A0A0A6YXS5     <NA>
#12 A0A0A6YXW8     Pak2
#13 A0A0A6YXX6 Arhgap15
#14 A0A0A6YXZ1     Igtp
#15 A0A0A6YY28      pol
#16 A0A0A6YY43     <NA>
#17 A0A0A6YY47   MumuTL
#18 A0A0A6YY78   MumuTL
#19 A0A0A6YY89     <NA>
#20 A0A0A6YY91   MumuTL
#21 A0A0A7NQN9     <NA>
```

I basically want to keep the order of the df1 the same and just paste the values in `to` wherever the from is similar .

Comment: Use `match`? `df2$to[match(df1$from,df2$from)]`

Comment: @Ronak Shah I have been trying to figure it out with merge. if you know any better way, please let me know . the command you tell me, does not produce the output I am looking for

Comment: The built-in `merge` does not keep row order. Are you open to non-base packages? `dplyr::left_join` or `data.table::merge` would both work easily.

Comment: @nik  I get the expected output with `data.frame(from = df1$from, to = df2$to[match(df1$from,df2$from)])`

Comment: @Ronak Shah thanks it is still not giving me what I am looking for. please give me a mitute probably I found where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::left_join` preserves row order, unlike `merge`. Using your larger example data:

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)
# Joining, by = "from"
#          from       to
# 1  A0A0A6YXQ7    Myo1f
# 2  A0A0A6YXS5     <NA>
# 3  A0A0A6YXW8     Pak2
# 4  A0A0A6YXX6 Arhgap15
# 5  A0A0A6YXZ1     Igtp
# 6  A0A0A6YY28      pol
# 7  A0A0A6YY43     <NA>
# 8  A0A0A6YY47   MumuTL
# 9  A0A0A6YY78   MumuTL
# 10 A0A0A6YY89     <NA>
# 11 A0A0A6YY91   MumuTL
# 12 A0A0A7NQN9     <NA>
# 13 A0A023J6K5      ND4
# 14 A0A023J6L7      ND1
# 15 A0A023J6M1      ND4
# 16 A0A067XG53     Cask
# 17 A0A067XKM5      ND1
# 18 A0A067XKP8     COXI
# 19 A0A067XKR4      ND4
# 20 A0A067XKW4      ND1
# 21 A0A067XKW7     <NA>
# Warning message:
# Column `from` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```